# Jupyter Notebook stuck at loading when importing data with pymongo to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

Everytime I run it, the cell stays loading and it never finishes. Data is 2mbs so it should load really fast. Pymongo was installed with pymongo[srv]. My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
import os 


pwd = os.getenv("mongodb_pwd")
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    f"mongodb+srv://...:{pwd}@.../test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=...&readPreference=primary&ssl=true"
)
db = client["general"]

data = db["orders"].find()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
```

any idea why this is happening? It used to work 2 weeks ago (under python 3.9, im using 3.10 now)

Ran the file as .py, still stuck.

After more than 5 minutes, the data was loaded. Any ideas why it is taking so long?

Comment: Exactly where is time being spent? ... `db["orders"].find()`? ... `list(data)`? ... `pd.DataFrame( ...`?

Answer (score 0):

restarted the pc and everything worked fast again. No idea what happened.